# Please give me an in depth analysis of PHP string function strcmp()

Tags: php, string, function, ascii

Consider the following program:

```
<?php
      $str1='Hello';
      $str2='hELLo';
      echo strcmp($str1,$str2);
?>
```

As per my knowledge:

1. At the point where first mismatch is found the ASCII value difference of the two characters are given.
2. If the first mismatch is found between a valid character and an empty character the extra number of characters of longer string is given as output.

Hence, the output of above character should be

ASCII value of `H` - ASCII value of `h`
= 72 - 104
= - 32

My browser gives the same output as well.

However in [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_strcmp2)

the answer is given as -1

Also in [phpdotnet](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

in user contributed notes section,  user luizvid at gmail dot come puts forward similar concept as given in w3schools.

Please clear my confusion.

Comment: I'd go with the actual result you get when running the code, not what a doc says. Try it and tell us as I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: What to try? I have already given my result, but two bibles of PHP w3 school and pho.net are saying otherwise

Comment: strcmp() is NOT designed to give an ASCII value difference, it is only a way to know that the strings differ. It is also NOT designed to tell you ***where*** in the string that it differs. This is why the return value information at php.net says: **Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.**

Comment: I mean the user contributed note of luzuvid and w3school arw giveng the result exactly as -1. But in brwser IT IS TAKING ASCII value difference which is a negative number but not explicitly -1

Comment: The point is that you can't depend on a particular value being returned, only the sign is guaranteed. The actual result may depend on the version of PHP.

Comment: PHP returns the ascii value difference while hhvm returns the sign (eg. just -1, 0, +1) of that: [Link](https://3v4l.org/NqH7j).

Comment: @ccKep only you could provide me the desired answer. Thank you. Please consider giving it as answer. Also it will be very kind of you if you could also explain me what is hhvm?

Comment: I have php 7.1.1, and the result I get running the sample code in Firefox is -1.

Comment: @PaulT [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NqH7j#output) says it returns -32 for 7.0.0 - 7.1.5. Might be system specific aswell (depending on the underlying implementation of C strcmp perhaps).

Comment: @cyano_learner HHVM is Facebooks php virtual machine. Basically a fork.

Comment: I have PHP 7.1.0 and on google chrome I am getting the output -32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap this question up:

The [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/strcmp) generally just state that you can rely on the **sign** of the result:

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

The effect that it returns the ASCII difference is just that, a side-effect and not guaranteed.

In fact, as of 2017-05-30:

- PHP 5.6.0 - 5.6.30 aswell as 7.0.0 - 7.1.5 return the **ASCII difference**

while

- [HHVM](http://hhvm.com/) 3.15.4 - 3.19.0 just returns the **sign**.

See [Link](https://3v4l.org/NqH7j#vhhvm-3154).

Long story short: Don't rely on `strcmp` for anything other than "Are these strings identical or not?".

Comment: As written in hhvm site itself it fully supports only php 5 and only the major features of php 7. Clearly hhvm can't be relied upon for php 7 development